# Local path in iis greyed out

Tags: iis-6, iis

I am trying to deploy an application to my website, but the Local Path in IIS Manager is greyed out. Why is this occurring?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

1. Expand the local computer, expand the Web Sites directory, right-click the Web site you wish to change, and click **Stop**.
2. In IIS Manager, right-click your Web site, and click **Properties**
3. Check the Home Directory tab, and under the content for this
   resource should come from, click **A directory located on this computer**

[image]